# $a^2+b^2+c^2=(abc)^2-2\leq 6$. Proof or counter-example needed for $a,b,c\gt 0$

Tags: inequality

I was working on an inequality proof in which I need to use the following inequality to conclude.

> $$\forall~a,b,c\gt 0~,~a^2+b^2+c^2=(abc)^2-2\implies a^2+b^2+c^2\leq 6$$

I can't think of any way to prove this. I only need a hint since I dislike people just giving away the answers. Thanks in advance!

If this claim is false, I'd like a counter-example. Thanks again!

Comment: If someone posts a proof, I need a proof that doesn't use calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reversed claim is true, which means the claim is false.
Put $s=x+y+z, x = a^2, y = b^2, z = c^2 \Rightarrow x+y+z = xyz-2 \leq \dfrac{(x+y+z)^3}{27} - 2 \Rightarrow s \leq \dfrac{s^3}{27}-2\Rightarrow s^3-27s-54 \geq 0 \Rightarrow (s-6)(s+3)^2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow s \geq 6.$

Comment: This makes me sad. :\

Comment: Yes, I knew that as well since you probably are hoping it is true so you can prove the harder inequality.

Comment: Yup! I was actually trying at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269281/prove-that-2abbcca-a2-b2-c2-le6) one.

Comment: Need to think of some new trick now. :P

Comment: you might want to look at some techniques like EV at AOP.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with those abbreviations. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Its the art of problem solving site. Are you familiar? they are dawn good at inequalities.

Comment: I am curious why you think it is false

Comment: It is true for some instances and false for others, so it is not true any more....

Comment: Ah! AoPS. Yes, I know about that, but I rarely visit that site. What did you mean by EV though? The only EV I know of is "Expected Value".

Comment: it means equal variables.

Comment: Ah, I see. Anyway, thanks for taking the time to help me with this. :)

Comment: How is the claim sometimes false?

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=a^2+b^2+c^2\geq 0$. We have
$$
(abc)^2=a^2b^2c^2\leq\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3}{27}=\frac{t^3}{27}.
$$
It follows from $a^2+b^2+c^2=(abc)^2-2$ that
$$
t\leq\frac{t^3}{27}-2.
$$
Therefore
$$
(t+3)^2(t-6)\geq 0.
$$
Since $(t+3)^2\geq 9$, we have $t\geq 6$.

Answer (score -3):

True for $a = b = c$, then $a = \sqrt{\frac{6}{3}} = \sqrt{2}$

$\sqrt{2}^2 + \sqrt{2}^2 + \sqrt{2}^2 = (\sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{2})^2 - 2$

$6 = 8-2$ and $6 \le 6$

$a,b,c = \sqrt{2} > 0$